# Fibonacii Sum Python

Tags: python

Hello guys I just need an idea for this part of my code in Python.

```
elif (opt == "2"):
         while(n>0):
             f = sumFib(n)
             print(f)
             n = n - f
```

OUTPUT 50:
34
13
3

My code works and does exactly what I want, it shows me the decomposed sum of a given number like 50, it shows me 34, 13, 3, my problem is next, I can't find a solution so that after pressing option 2 in my menu it will show me a text like "The sum of the Fibonacci series of the decomposed number is: 50 = 34 + 13 + 3" can you give me a suggestion about how I should process that piece of menu to show me how I want it?

EDIT: Thank you all for the suggestions, I solved the problem with the help of @Kartik Behl's suggestion, whoever encounters a similar problem I recommend his code.

Comment: "My code works and does exactly what I want, "  congratulations!  What exactly is your problem with printing that out?

Comment: my code is not just that, it's just a small part that I want to modify so that after pressing options 2 in the console to display my message and the desired arrangement, the project I'm working on works, what you see there is only option 2 in the main, on short to understand, I run start my menu press 1 enter the desired number after pressing option two and it appears as I specified, I have no errors in the code only I want to find a solution to appear as I want...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
elif opt == '2':
num = n
decomposedSum = []
while(n>0):
    f = sumFib(n)
    decomposedSum.append(str(f))
    n = n - f
print(f"The sum of the Fibonacci series of the decomposed number is: {num} = {'+'.join(decomposedSum)}")
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's exactly what I needed, I didn't think to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
elif (opt == "2"):
     print("The sum of the Fibonacci series of the decomposed number is: ", end="")
     while(n>0):
         f = sumFib(n)
         print(f)
         n = n - f
```

Comment: thank you I didn't think to write that print like that the result appeared to me even after the prince. the only problem that remains, my numbers appear vertically and I can't find the solution to make them look 50 = 34 + 13 + 3 in the final display.

Comment: Add end="" at the end in the print statement where your numbers are being printed just like how I did with that print("The sum of.....") sentence.